# Decoding a recursive []interface{} to []struct{} using mapstructure.Decode returns nil?

Tags: go, struct, interface, type-conversion

I am working on project where I need to work with a struct where in one field (Next) recursivly uses the same struct. The reason for this is that the JSON data that I use for parsing comes from a proces diagram where the following next steps are connected.

I have to following struct:

```golang
type Component struct {
    Title string `json:"title"`
    Name  string `json:"name"`
}

type Inputs struct {
    VMname          string `json:"VMname"`
    ServerRole      string `json:"serverRole"`
    Os              string `json:"os"`
    AppSearch       string `json:"appsearch"`
    Platform        string `json:"platform"`
    Location        string `json:"location"`
    Msp             string `json:"msp"`
    Zone            string `json:"zone"`
    Networklot      string `json:"networklot"`
    FrontendSubnet  string `json:"frontendSubnet"`
    CPU             string `json:"cpu"`
    Memory          string `json:"memory"`
    Storage         int    `json:"storage"`
    ApplicationName string `json:"applicationName"`
}

type Components []struct {
    Component   Component `json:"component"`
    Inputs      Inputs    `json:"inputs"`
    InputErrors struct {
    } `json:"inputErrors"`
    ID   string        `json:"id"`
    Next []interface{} `json:"next"` //this could be a Components []struct or []
}
```

I've came on this struct by using the [JSON-to-go converter](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) where I've put in the following JSON:

```
[
    {
        "component": {
            "title": "title1",
            "name": "name1"
        },
        "inputs": {
            "serverRole": "server1",
            "os": "coolOS",
            "platform": "platform",
            "location": "New York",
            "msp": "msp",
            "zone": "red",
            "networklot": "kavel",
            "frontendSubnet": "0.0.0.0/8080",
            "cpu": "2",
            "memory": "2",
            "VMname": "hola1",
            "appsearch": "ann",
            "storage": 0,
            "applicationName": "app1"
        },
        "inputErrors": {},
        "id": "UwLfQBijlijMqKOCeWdI",
        "next": [
            {
                "component": {
                    "title": "title1",
                    "name": "name2"
                },
                "inputs": {
                    "serverRole": "server2",
                    "os": "coolOS2",
                    "platform": "platform",
                    "location": "Amsterdam",
                    "msp": "msp",
                    "zone": "red",
                    "networklot": "kavel",
                    "frontendSubnet": "0.0.0.0/8081",
                    "cpu": "4",
                    "memory": "4",
                    "VMname": "hola2",
                    "appsearch": "ann",
                    "storage": 10,
                    "applicationName": "app2"
                },
                "inputErrors": {},
                "id": "1hzFLlSX6T7B3q8IwcpX",
                "next": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The problem/or challange lies in the `"next"` in the JSON data and the corrensponding `Next []interface{}` in the `Components` struct. You can see that in the JSON data that the first next contains a other JSON array with the same data structure as it's parent, but that is not always the case as you can see the second next has a empty array. Which means that there aren't anymore childern and the flow reacted it's end.

So in short the Next field in the `[]Components struct` could be `[]Components struct` or empty slice. So after looking on the internet I've found that you can use a `[]interface{}` as field for a `struct[]` or empty slice.

Next I use `json.Unmarshal` to parse the JSON data into the struct where I get the following correct result:

```
components: <Components> (length: 1, cap: 4)
    [0]: <struct { Component, Inputs, InputErrors struct{}, ID string, Next []interface{} }>
        Component: Component
        Inputs: Inputs
        InputsErrors: struct{}
        ID: "dkjfjdkjfd"
        Next: []interface {} (length: 1, cap: 4)
```

and where the `Next` field equals to the following:

```
Next <[]interface {}> (length: 1, cap: 4)
    [0] <interface {}(map[string]interface {})>)
        data: <map[string]interface {}> (length: 5)
            "component" <interface {}(map[string]interface {})>)
            "inputs" <interface {}(map[string]interface {})>)
            "inputErrors" <interface {}(map[string]interface {})>)
            "id" <interface {}(string)>)
            "next" <interface {}([]interface {})>)
                data: <[]interface {}> (length: 0, cap: 0) //when the length is 0 then the flow is at it's end.
```

Now I would like to do the following steps:

1. Loop over the `[]Components struct` (in a function)
2. Check in the loop if the next `length == 0`, if so break the loop because we are at the end.
3. Loop over the Next field inside the `[]Component struct` loop.
4. Set a new variable called nextComponents.
5. Call `mapstructure.decode(n, &nextComponents)` from the [mapstructure](https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure) package.
6. Recursively call the loop over the `[]Components struct` with as argument `nextComponents`

Small code example:

```golang
func DeployDiagram(input interface{}) map[int]types.NewSystemResponse { 
    components := input.(types.Components)
    for i, component := range components {
        //do some logic
        //...
        //...

        //1. check if next slice == 0 if so then break loop
        //2. loop over the next []interface to interface{}
        //3. convert interface{} to types.Components
        //4. DeployDiagram(types.Components) recursive call
        if len(component.Next) == 0 {
            break //we are in the last object from the diagram no more next objects.
        }

        for _, n := range component.Next {
            var nextComponents types.Components
            mapstructure.Decode(n, &nextComponents) //this end's up being nil?
            DeployDiagram(nextComponents)
        }
    }

    return someThing
}
```

The problem is that nextComponents returns nil, while it should return a new `[]Components{}` struct. I think that I am really close, but I can't see what I am doing wrong because I don't get any errors and I am not sure if this is the correct way.

Any suggestions or advice are welcome. Thank you. :)

Comment: why are you using interface in a first place? Why not just use slice?

Comment: Because the Next field can be two different types []struct{} or []. So thats why the []interface{}.

Comment: so firstly, why would you store []strunct{}, thats absolutly useles. Secondly no sutch type as [] exist in golang. if json array is empty it does not matter what type  of slice it parses into.

Comment: So I can just use a slice and dont worry about if the next field is a empty slice or not? Can you perhaps give me a small example? And what type should the slice be then? Because it could be from the type components struct or empty?

Comment: well perhaps i can

Comment: just change the interface{} to Components and try to parse the json, it should work flawlesly

Comment: Ok I will try that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231893/discussion-between-tobias-s-and-jakub-doka).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The json parser in go does not differentiate between empty array and filled array. You can use `Components` instead of `[]interface{}`, even if there is nothing in the json array, it will parse it just fine.